# Random Key Select From MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, benchmarking, nosql

I am trying to insert a large set of data into MongoDb and retrieve random keys values from the collection. It takes about 29mins inserting about 2GB of data and several hours retrieving the key value pairs. This is very slow compared to other NoSQL datastore. What might possibly be the bottleneck.

**INSERTING**

```
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                 documentDetail.clear();
                 //String strLines = strLine.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
                 tokens = strLine.split("\t");

                 documentDetail.put("key", tokens[0]);
                 documentDetail.put("value", tokens[1]);
                 start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 collection.insert(documentDetail);  
                 elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
                 totalElapsed += elapsed;
              }
          BasicDBObject index = new BasicDBObject(); 
          index.put("key", 1);  
          index.put("value", 1);  
          collection.ensureIndex(index);
```

**SELECTING**

```
        BasicDBObject find = new BasicDBObject();
        find.put("value", 1);
        while ((strLin = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("key", strLin);

        System.out.println(strLin);
         start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find(query, find);  
        while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {  
            System.out.println(cursorDoc.next());  
        }  
        elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
        totalElapsed += elapsed;  
        System.out.println("Reading Ends...");
          //field.clear();
      }
```

Comment: Do you have an index set on `key`? Also, where is `name` coming from?

Comment: I just edited the code. I did not add index set on key, probably thats the reason. How can I do that

Comment: Don't know your collection name nor the Java API very well, but from the mongodb cli something like `db.<collectionname>.ensureIndex( { key: 1 } )`. You can add more options to the index such as uniqueness, automatic replace on collision etc. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex).

Comment: I indexed both the key and the value. It took several minutes doing that and there was no difference in the time to read random keys from the collection, taking several hours

Comment: Very odd, an index should speed things up significantly. What data type are the keys? Long strings? How did you create the index? Separate indexes for key and value or some kind of combination?

Comment: They are both Strings. I used ' BasicDBObject index = new BasicDBObject(); 
     index.put("key", 1);  
     index.put("value", 1);  
     collection.ensureIndex(index); and I did it immediately after inserting the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does your index fit into RAM? If not, MongoDB will be very unhappy (=slow).

   ```
   > db.collection.totalIndexSize()
   ```
2. To make it an index only scan / covered index, use the following:

   ```
   BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("key",true).append("_id",false);
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed MongoDB was very unhappy. I applied your suggestion and it takes just 2mins to read the random keys. Please its there a way to speed up the insert too?

Comment: look into bulk inserts, that should help http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/